# Is there a specific chemical reaction between capsaicin and casein? Is there a stoichiometric relationship between them?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stoichiometry

I am trying to establish the reaction between capsaicin and casein in order to neutralize the effects of the capsaicin. Therefore, I must determine if there is a reaction and a stoichiometric relation.

Answer (score 2):

I rather doubt that there's a significant binding between capsaicin and the protein casein or a stoichiometric reaction.

[image: capsaicin]

If you look at the structure of capsaicin, you'll recognize that it's a rather unpolar molecule. With other words, it is hardly soluble in water, but will dissolve in oil. This is exactly where the fats in milk come into play. The "neutralizing" effect of milk with respect to the sensory "hotness" of capsaicin is just the solution of the unpolar compound in an unpolar solvent.

Comment: I would be very surprised if there was absolutely no interaction between the two but I would not be surprised if the interaction were in any way specific.